# Clustered-index on something else than auto Identity key column and inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, clustered-index

I have a performance problem on a table with a few million rows that is being queried a lot in a short amount of time (hundreds per minute).

For simplification say the table looks like this:

```
Id   UserId   ValueA   ValueB   ValueC   Etc
--------------------------------------------
1    1        X        X        X        "
2    1        X        X        X        "
3    2        X        X        X        "
4    2        X        X        X        "
5    2        X        X        X        "
6    3        X        X        X        "
```

I quite often query the table on the `UserId` column and then I take all the rows and columns related.

Now I'm getting an automatic Azure recommendation to create an index on `UserId` and take the other columns as **included columns**. As I understand correctly it just makes a duplicate of the whole data.

Now I'm thinking if I can fix this by just making the `UserId` the clustered index.

Next to a lot of reads, this table also sometimes suffers quite some inserts (on moments could be hundreds of individual rows per minute, but can't be batched for now)

I'm just concerned that these individual Inserts will be getting slower and slower, because it needs to physically move the data around constantly to keep the clustered index intact.

I know that in the end I need to test it all out, but are there any guidelines here?

Is there something like a guideline i.e. that says for a table with a lot of individual inserts always put the clustered index on the identity column?

Comment: What's the performance problem? SQL will suggest an index based on some very simplistic rules, but may not be a good idea. Additionally, changing the clustered index of a table is a big deal.

Comment: Performance-related questions are better to ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is like a guideline that for a table with a lot of individual inserts, a clustered index on the identify column is a good idea.  That is because the inserts go to the "end" of the table, and don't result in page splits.

[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68639/identity-column-as-clustured-index-bad-idea?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is an interesting discussion on the topic.

Ironically, creating an index and including all the columns only shifts the problem to the index.  I'm not sure if that is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem a lot before. I have found to have multiple indexes work well. The goal is to not have each attribute be indexed, but if you notice that you are querying for a single attribute, or a few attributes, often then make those indexed along with your key. The thing to watch out for is that this will take up a lot of data as each index will be a copy of the table, so as the table grows so do the inserts. This may also affect insert times, but if you are querying more than inserting than this could be useful.

I know in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) there is a way to see the exact path that the query executor took to get the response output, and this also tells where it spend the most time. This would be a good spot to start looking at where to index a field or not.